# Way to hide the OpenStreetMap country boundaries in the sea in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

Is there a way to remove the maritime country borders on a map? (Without using Mapbox). I'm new to leaflet and openstreetmap so may be overlooking something obvious.

How it currently looks:

[image]

What I'd like it to look like:

[image]

Comment: probably need to see your code your have. see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:maritime%3Dyes

Comment: @Mapperz the code is currently inside a WP plugin that has its own api so I think the Leaflet API is the best reference point. Can the maritime tag be referenced by the Leaflet JS API at all? I had a look but couldn't find which bit this would be https://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to find OSM source that offers that kind of a map. It can be raster tile or WMS source.

Here is an example of such a source:

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("https://{s}maps.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms", {
  subdomains: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
  layers: "osm:osm",
  format: 'image/png'
});
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks TomazicM this looks very interesting. I will try this.

Is there a list of these OSM sources? Also not sure what the T&Cs would be of using such an endpoint on a website or if they expect people to just go ahead and use it.

Comment: I'm not aware of OSM sources list. Different OSM styles are available from the site https://maps.geo-solutions.it. You can get a list of layers with https://maps.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities request. What are requirements for using these you'll have to ask them.

Comment: [Leaflet Provider Demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) has many different OSM-based tile servers.